# How to override the protected method afterlogin or use EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN in User model?

Tags: events, authentication, yii2

I have a User model which implements `IdentityInterface`.

I want to perform some action after the user is `logged in by cookie`. I am trying to override the `afterLogin` method in `User` class.

**yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php**

```
protected function afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration)
    {
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, new UserEvent([
            'identity' => $identity,
            'cookieBased' => $cookieBased,
            'duration' => $duration,
        ]));
    }
```

How to use override the above method in User model. Or how can I use the EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` in `bootstrap.php`. It may help someone in future.

Add the below code in `bootstrap.php` file.

```
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\User;

Event::on(User::className(), User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function() {
    // your code
});
```

But still the question remains how can I override the afterLogin method in User model.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = new Foo;

// this handler is a global function
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, 'function_name');

// this handler is an object method
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, [$object, 'methodName']);

// this handler is a static class method
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, ['app\components\Bar', 'methodName']);

// this handler is an anonymous function
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, function ($event) {
    // event handling logic
});
```

This examples are taken from [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#attaching-event-handlers). This is a way to handle an event.

I think you just need to use User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN instead.

Comment: Also here's almost same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864280/override-user-afterlogin-method?rq=1

Comment: I added the afterlogin function in User model but it is not working. I find out how to use EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN. But still my question is can't we override the afterLogin function in User model instead of using event?